# Don't add items if it doesn't match the filter

Tags: android, listview, filter

```
        private class NameFilter extends Filter
    {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<Order> filt = new ArrayList<Order>();
                ArrayList<Order> lItems = new ArrayList<Order>();
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    lItems.addAll(items);
                }
                for(int i = 0, l = lItems.size(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    Order m = lItems.get(i);
                    if(m.getOrderTitle().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)
                            || m.getOrderTime().toLowerCase().contains(constraint) ||
                            m.getOrderPrice().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filt.add(m);                     
                }
                result.count = filt.size();
                result.values = filt;

            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = items;
                    result.count = items.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filtered = (ArrayList<Order>)results.values;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.clear();
            if(!constraint.equals("")){
            for(int i = 0; i < filtered.size(); i++){
                adapter.add(filtered.get(i));
                adapter.setId(i, filtered.get(i).getOrderId());
            }
            }

            else {
                if(orders!=null){
                 for(int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++){
                adapter.add(orders.get(i));
                adapter.setId(i, orders.get(i).getOrderId());
                 }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

The items in the ListView comes from an AsyncTask. When the AsyncTask is running I want it to stop adding non-matching items. For now, if it had loaded 5 items and I search with a specified String, then when the AsyncTask continues loading items it adds automatically Orders to the ListView, even if there isn't a match.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance and tell me if the question is unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your earlier question(s) here on SO, you can check in `onProgressUpdate` if your `EditText` is empty or not. If it contains some text, then filter it at that point.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i) { 

   CharSequence cs = yourEditText.getText().toString(); //Get text
   if(!cs.equals("")){ //Check if "cs" contains text
      adapter.add(orders.get(i[0])); //Add it to the adapter, then...    
      adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); //..do your filtering, and...
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //...update your View
   }
   else { //Otherwise, just add the order to your adapter..
       adapter.add(orders.get(i[0])); 
   }

}
```

We always add **all** orders (even if the `EditText` contains information) to make sure that all orders show up when `EditText` is empty.